# How to target Oracle 11g instead of 12 for EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g

Im working on a web api project developed with .net entity framework and oracle 11g DB.
Some of the generated statements contain things like "FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY" which I believe are only supported in Oracle 12. How can I configure the project to tell entity framework that it should generate statements compatible with Oracle 11?

Comment: Since 11g has been obsolete for a while now and 12c is mostly out of support as well, you may not be able to do that with current developer tools. The only really "current" supported versions of Oracle at the moment (for any practical development purposes) are 19c and 21c.